# DoubleTapToGo - Not Working On This Site, Works On My Other Sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

Can't seem to figure out why [DoubleTapToGo](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) isn't working on this custom WordPress site on mobile (ie "Firm Overview" dropdown). This theme was coded using [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and [Underscores](http://underscores.me/), but has had Foundation's responsiveness "removed" via some hacks (there is another site I made that was built exactly the same way, with DoubleTapToGo working fine, so I must be missing something).

If someone could take a peek and see if they have any idea why it's not working right I'd be much obliged. Here is a link to the dev page http://schneider.asenka.com/ (pay special attention to the "Firm Overview" dropdown as that's the only one that is also a link to a page)

Thanks!

Comment: I have since just made the top level menu items just link to #. So it sort of works that way, but if anyone has any idea how to make it work if # was an actual link, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Just for anyone having a problem with DoubleTapToGo in the future. It ended up being that the JS file that was in the download from the site was corrupted somehow, though I was able to open it fine in sublime. So I just copy/pasted the code from it into another file and saved that to the site and it took care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was posted more than one year ago, I still find it useful to tell that there is a plugin for WordPress which adds the double tap functionality to drop-down navigation menus with only one click.

The plugin is called Black Studio Touch Dropdown Menu, and can be found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-touch-dropdown-menu/

Had the problem with DoubleTapToGo for a while, and now I've just found this useful plugin which just works without any configuration.